# Como configurar para abrir otro proyecto con Laravel+Homestead en Windows

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, laravel-4

He hecho la configuración en los siguientes archivos. También realice el comando `vagrant up` y luego `vagrant reload --provision` y otro comando `vagrant-hostsupdater`. Honestamente no puedo visualizar en el navegador mi otro proyecto, pero si el primer proyecto, como puedo configurarlo?

```js
Estoy usando laravel+homested en Windows
donde tengo mis proyectos es en está dirección
C:\Users\e.herrera\Desktop\laravel\Code
un proyecto se llama laracast y otro myfirstsitelaravel
mi Homestead está en dirección C:\Users\e.herrera\Homestead
```

```css
#he configurado el .Homestead.yaml en está dirección
#my C:\Users\e.herrera\.homestead
ip: "192.168.10.10" 
memory: 2048 
cpus: 1 
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys: - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders: 
- map: C:\Users\e.herrera\Desktop\laravel\Code 
to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites: 
- map: dev.app 
to: /home/vagrant/Code/myfirstsitelaravel/public 
- map: larabook.app 
to: /home/vagrant/Code/laracast/public
databases: - homestead
#blackfire:
#- id: foo
#token: bar
#client-id: foo
#client-token: bar
#ports:
#- send: 50000
#to: 5000
#- send: 7777
#to: 777
#protocol: udp
```

```html
hosts
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
space.
#
Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
For example:
#
102.54.94.97 rhino.acme.com # source server
38.25.63.10 x.acme.com # x client host
localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#127.0.0.1 localhost
#::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 homestead.app 
127.0.0.1 dev.app
192.168.10.10 peliroja.app
```

Comment: ¿cuál proyecto funciona y cuál no?

Comment: lo he solucionado mis disculpas seguí esto
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983555/setting-up-a-second-homestead-laravel-app?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Tomar en cuenta que toda esta configuracion la tienes que hacer despues de ejecutar vagrant up y luego haces las siguientes configuraciones.

```js
Ingresar a esta direccion y abrir el archivo hosts con un editor de texto con permiso de administrador y colocar lo siguiente

direccion -> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
127.0.0.1 myfirstsitelaravel.app
127.0.0.1 laracast.app
```

```css
direccion donde tengo creado mis proyetos es en 
C:\Users\e.herrera\Desktop\laravel\Code
```

```html
configurar el archivo Homestead.yaml que esta ubicado en C:\Users\e.herrera\.homestead y el archivo se llama Homestead.yaml puedes abrirlo con un editor de texto con permiso de administrador

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\e.herrera\Desktop\laravel\Code\myfirstsitelaravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/myfirstsitelaravel
    - map: C:\Users\e.herrera\Desktop\laravel\Code\laracast
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laracast

sites:
    - map: myfirstsitelaravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/myfirstsitelaravel/public
    - map: laracast.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laracast/public
```

al final corres vagrant reload --provision